# Train station involving probability

Tags: probability

Mrs. Johnson comes to the train station at a random time every day
and decides to hop in the first train.

There are two trains; the uptown and downtown trains which
come every 10 minutes at the same train stop.

Here is the train schedule:

Uptown Train-----   Downtown train

1:00 pm------------         1:01 pm

1:20 pm------------         1:21 pm

1:30 pm------------     1:31 pm

and so on---------- and so on

For ninety percent of the time, Mrs. Johnson 
ends up taking the uptown train. Why is this the case?

My teacher mentioned this problem involves probability but i'm not really seeing it.

A day has 24 hours from 12am-12 pm it seems that in one hour, Mrs. Johnson can take the uptown train 1:00 pm, 1:10, 1:20 pm, 1:30 pm, 1:40 pm, 1:50 pm and 2:00. So in our hour, she has 7 tries

However, for the downtown train, in one hour between 1-2pm, Mrs. Johnson can take the train at 1:01pm, 1:11 pm, 1:21 pm, 1:31 pm, 1:41 pm, 1:51 pm so she has 6 tries to hop in the bus.

I'm not sure how this problem is working and then there is that ninety percent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the time that she arrives. If she arrives in the first minute of a given 10 minute block (for example, between 1:00 and 1:01), then she will take the downtown train, but otherwise she will take the following uptown train.